# Problema em trabalhar com resolução com Bootstrap

Tags: css

Observem a imagem;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Vocês podem perceber que a resolução fica do jeito que eu quero com ela está pequena porém ela estoura quando fica com uma resolução maior.

Como eu poderia corrigir isso?

aqui está o código HTML

```
 <!--INICIO DO CONTEUDO-->
 <section class="content-header">
   <h1>Lista de Restaurantes</h1>
</section>

<section class="content">
  <section class="invoice">

    <form >
      <div class="col-lg-12" >

              <table class="table table-hover">
                  <thead class="thead-default">
                    <tr>
                      <th>Nome</th>
                      <th>Ano</th>
                      <th>Ação</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                    <tr *ngFor="let restaurant of restaurants">
                      <td>{{ restaurant.name }}</td>
                      <td>{{ restaurant.category }}</td>
                      <td>
                        botão
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
              </table>
        </div>
      </form>

  </section>
</section>
<!-- FIM DO CONTEUDO-->
```

Comment: Qual Bootstrap?

Comment: Só por curiosidade. Qual foi a ferramenta que você usou para criar o ani gif? (vou deletar este comentário se o autor não responder)

Comment: eu estou usando esse site :P       `https://convertio.co/pt/mp4-gif/`  kkkkkk

Comment: @LeAndrade acabei de corrigir, eu tirei a classe CSS `col-lg-12`

Comment: Qual versão do Bootstrap está usando? Vc tem algum CSS nessa tabela além do default do Bootstrap? Se tiver inclua na pergunta ok.

Comment: @hugocsl me desculpe não ter mencionado, mas eu não sei se você tem acompanhado os comentários mas eu já resolvi o problema. Eu estou usando o `admin-lte`

Comment: Ah legal então! Tente criar uma resposta para sua própria pergunta. Dessa forma em depois dias se não me engano vc pode marcar sua própria resposta como aceita e ela não fica mais como pendente de resposta no site.

Comment: Muito obrigado @hugocsl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá @wlandyband, a correção mais certa para este tipo de caso é `.clearfix` para as divisórias ou elementos pais que herdam os `.col`, como os `.col`, possui atributo `float: left;` ele faz que flutue o elemento numa segunda camada e como o elemento que herda o background, creio que no seu caso o `.invoice` ou `.content` ele não tinha o atributo `clear: both;` fazendo que quando você diminuísse a resolução saindo da resolução da class `.col-lg` ele perdesse então o atributo de flutuação fazendo esse pequeno bug.

Para entender melhor segue [link da documentação do clearfix no Bootstrap v4, porém também tem a explicação nas versões anteriores.](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/clearfix/)

Segue também um print visualmente do uso em prática.

Sem .clearfix
[image]

Com .clearfix
[image]

Outro link que irá ajudar a entender melhor o por que do uso do `.clearfix`, que é apenas um atributo do css `clear: both;` para corrigir esse problema.

[Exemplo do atributo clear:both;](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_clear.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Por eu está usando o admin-lte tive que tirar a classe `col-lg-12` ficou assim

```
<!--INICIO DO CONTEUDO-->
 <section class="content-header">
   <h1>Lista de Restaurantes</h1>
</section>

<section class="content">
  <section class="invoice">



              <table class="table table-hover">
                  <thead class="thead-default">
                    <tr>
                      <th>Nome</th>
                      <th>Ano</th>
                      <th>Ação</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                    <tr *ngFor="let restaurant of restaurants">
                      <td>{{ restaurant.name }}</td>
                      <td>{{ restaurant.category }}</td>
                      <td>
                        botão
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
              </table>

  </section>
</section>
<!-- FIM DO CONTEUDO-->
```